# NHibernate is returning a cached value, but it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching, wcf-data-services

We have a WCF Data Service using an NHibernateDataContext (`RecipeDataContext : NHibernateDataContext`)

It exposes Recipes as follows

```
    public IQueryable<Recipe> Recipes
    {
        get
        {
            var x = new NhQueryable<Recipe>(Session.GetSessionImplementation());
            return x;
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting the cachemode to ignore

```
            var newSession = Session.GetSessionImplementation();
            newSession.CacheMode = CacheMode.Ignore;

            var x = new NhQueryable<Recipe>(newSession);
            return x;
```

And we SEE the query hit the database with SQL Server Profiler.  That query returns the correct value. However, "`x`", contains the old value, before it was modified.

How do we get this to ignore the cache, and query the database?

Comment: try to clear the session before querying in order to find out more

Comment: clearing the session results in the query getting the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in the session's first-level cache aren't automatically refreshed from the database. This is normally not a problem because very often each separate request from the client initiates a new session.

Comment: But why did it make the database request, and then use the cached value anyways? That makes no sense

Comment: Because if an active session contains an object instance, NHibernate won't just go ahead an modify your object just because some other process has altered that database. Since you submit a query it will query the DB to figure out which objects to return, but if any of those objects are already loaded in this session they will be reused - the session will not contain duplicates.

Comment: Oskar Berggren, my point is, if it's going to use the cached value, why is it wasting time, and resources querying the database?

Comment: Like I said: "...to figure out which objects to return..."

Comment: Put another way: even if it did implement a query engine that analyzed the objects in memory, how could it now that no other, as yet unloaded, object wouldn't match?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, there could be MORE objects...I'll have to test that though, as I don't think it was adding new objects.